# How should I structure my code when the MVC's model do not match the database model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm new to ASP.Net MVC and I'm having a question I can't seem to find the answer to on the Googles.

I have a page that needs a model that is significantly different from the way the data is stored in the database. It's trivial for me to write a function that would translate from the database model to the required MVC model (`MyModel ConvertToMvcModel(DataFromDatabase d`).

My question, where should I put this code? Should it be in the controler. Should it be in the Data access layer (Using the repository pattern).

Another related question is where should I put the repository class? Up until now I've put repository classes allong side the model class in the same .cs file since every model had a corresponding repository. This time the model will be different from what I get from the repository so it does not make much sense to put it in the same file. Maybe I should separate all my DAL (repositories) from the model code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please consider marking this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question, where should I put this code?

The mapping between your domain models and view models should ideally be placed inside a separate and dedicated mapping layer. For example if you use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), which I would recommend, you could place your mapping definitions inside separate files called profiles and inside the controller action simply call the `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>` method.

> Another related question is where should I put the repository class?
>   Up until now I've put repository classes allong side the model class
>   in the same .cs file since every model had a corresponding repository.

The DAL represents the data access layer and is where the repositories should go. You could define a common contract (interface) that the repositories must obey (implement) and then have several implementations against the different data sources that you are working with.

Comment: Tell me if I understand correctly. I should always do the translation between domain models (what comes out of the database) and my view models and I should not pass the domain models directly to the view.

Comment: Exactly, that's one of the most important rules.

Comment: It does makes sense, but I did not knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return entities anyway, use ViewModels for that purpose.

Regarding the mapping: what you're looking for already exists, it's called [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). You can let the service layer return entities to your controller, and the controller will map them to ViewModel objects.

Keep in mind to initialize the mappings only one time, so launch them from your application start.